# Can one jar be created using Izpack?

Tags: java, izpack

I want to know that If there is still a requirement for one jar while using Exe4j.

And can one jar be created using Izpack?

Answer (score 0):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [org.dstovall.onejar-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) then yes. It can be combined with IzPack Maven plugin into one pom.